# square root of two is 1.41..., can we evaluate infinite(th) root of 2?

Tags: limits, radicals

I was just thinking about square roots. and then a thought struck me.
since square root of $2 = 2^{1/2} = 1.414..$
      cube root of $2 = 2^{1/3} = 1.259$
then  $2^{1/\infty} = 2^{0} = 1$
is this true that whatever number we take, $n^{1/\infty}$ root will be 1?
please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This is what we call the "limit," and yes, you can do this, sort of. We avoid using $\infty$ as a number because it can lead to lots of careless errors, but the limit of $2^{1/n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity is indeed $1$. You will have to wait until Calculus to get the deeper details.

Comment: For example, you might think of a circle as an "infinity-gon" - a polygon with infinite sides. This view, though, can cause problems/paradoxes, so in mathematics, we express this more formally as a "limit" of regular $n$-gons.

Answer (score 4):

We tend to avoid treating $\infty$ as a number, because we lose a lot of nice rules about numbers when we do so.

What we do talk about is "limits." So we can look at the sequence of numbers:

$$2^{1/2},2^{1/3},2^{1/4},\dots$$

and we say that this sequence "has limit $1$" or that it "converges to $1$." Most students don't learn explicitly about limits until they get to calculus.

Most likely, the first place where you implicitly encountered a limit (without it being called such) is in repeated decimals.

For example, we write: $$\frac{1}{3}=0.3333\dots$$

This doesn't mean that $\frac{1}{3}=0.3$, nor does it mean that $\frac{1}{3}=0.33$. It means, rather, that $\frac{1}{3}$ is the "limit" of the sequence of numbers $$0.3,0.33,0.333,0.3333,\dots,$$

It took mathematicians a remarkably long time to formalize this notion of limit - it wasn't until the 19th century that they did so, even though they were implicitly using limits for much longer.

Comment: So is it always true that if a sequence has a limit, it will converge to that number.

Comment: Well, the definition of "limit" and "converge to" are the same definition, so yes. But that is a truism, so it might not be what you meant to ask.

Comment: It is not true that just because $\frac 12,\frac 13,\dots$ converges to zero that $f(1/2),f(1/3),\dots$ always converges to $f(0)$. The reason this works for $f(x)=2^x$ is because of a related concept from Calculus: continuity. A function is continuous, roughly, if its graph never jumps/has gaps. Most functions you know are continuous. So the reason $2^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ is that $1/n$ converges to $0$ and $2^x$ is "continuous at $x=0$."

Answer (score -4):

Yes, infiniteth root of $2$ is $1$.

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \sqrt[x]{2}=1$$

Comment: Don't encourage abuse of terminology. The limit is not the same as "the inifnitieth root," and you lead young students down the wrong path if you say it "is" $1$. You can say, "there is a way to formalize this notion, but..."